# Is torsion submodule of a $p$-adically complete and separated $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-module closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, topological-algebras

I was asking to myself the following question. Consider a $p$-adically complete and separated topological algebra $R$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. As $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a domain, we know that the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-torsion elements of $R$ form a submodule. Is it possible to prove that this torsion is a closed submodule of $R$? I'm interested in the possibility of saying that the quotient of $R$ over its torsion is again $p$-adically complete, but in order to do this, I think I need that the torsion submodule is closed. Have you got any idea? I tried to prove it by hands but I didn't reach anything useful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Take
$$
R=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z},
$$
with the product topology. Every non-empty open set in $R$ contains an element that is $0$ in all but finitely many factors, and this element is $\mathbb{Z}_p$-torsion. This means the torsion is dense, and since $1\in R$ is not torsion, the torsion submodule is not closed.

Comment: Isn't the $p$-adic topology on $R$ strictly finer than the product topology? One could rather consider the $p$-adic completion $\widehat{S}$ of $S = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, $\widehat{S}$ is $p$-adically complete with dense $p$-torsion (it is isomorphic to the submodule of $R$ consisting of those elements whose components have $p$-valuation going to infinity).